# Angular APP_INITIALIZER saying data has changed, but cant figure it out

Tags: angular

We have this message below which I know many people will have seen before, so please give me time to explain

```
NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'true'
```

We load some config using the **APP_INITIALIZER** as follows in the **app.modules.ts** file

```
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initialiseConfiguration, deps: [ConfigurationService], multi: true},
```

This then calls the following function

```
export function initialiseConfiguration(configurationService: ConfigurationService) {
    return (): Promise<any> => {
        return configurationService.init();
    };
}
```

The **ConfigurationService** looks like this

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {

    private configuration: IConfiguration | undefined;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {
    }

    get data(): IConfiguration | undefined {
        return this.configuration;
    }

    get features(): any {
        return this.configuration?.features;
    }

    init(): Promise<IConfiguration | undefined> {
        const url = "/Configuration";
        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get<IConfiguration>(url).subscribe({
                next: response => {
                    this.configuration = response;
                    resolve(this.configuration);
                }
            })
        });
    }
}
```

We now want to use that data to turn a component on and off by storing the features for use in the html. You can see we set it in the ngOnInit.

```
export class UserPageComponent implements OnInit {
    features: any;

    constructor(
        private configurationService: ConfigurationService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.features = this.configurationService.features;
    }
...
```

The html bit looks like this, I believe the important bit is the **ngIf** that checks the features and only displays the component if it is true.

```
<p-tabPanel header="General" *ngIf="features.userAdditionalDetails">
    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
        <sym-general-tab [user]="user" *ngIf="user"></sym-general-tab>
    </ng-template>
</p-tabPanel>
```

This all works but we get the message as shown at the top, we have tried all sorts but nothing works to get rid of it, only removing the ngIf and then we don't get an issue.

```
NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
```

Can anyone see what might be wrong? We can't see how this value would have changed, as we believe that this configurationService is loaded before anything else. It should have the data. There is also nothing that we can see that is changing this data after is has been loaded!???

### As an addition

This is the full html, even with the control removed and I have just put the text **Test**, we still get the error. If I remove the ng-template inside then the error stops strangely, so is it something to do with the templates shown?

```
<p-card styleClass="sym-card-content">
    <p-breadcrumb [model]="breadcrumb" *ngIf="breadcrumb"></p-breadcrumb>
    <p-tabView [(activeIndex)]="activeTab">
        
        <p-tabPanel header="General" *ngIf="features.userAdditionalDetails">
            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                Test
            </ng-template>
        </p-tabPanel>

        <p-tabPanel header="Group">
            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                <sym-group-tab [user]="user" *ngIf="user"></sym-group-tab>
            </ng-template>
        </p-tabPanel>

        <p-tabPanel header="Role">
            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                <sym-role-tab [user]="user" *ngIf="user"></sym-role-tab>
            </ng-template>
        </p-tabPanel>

        <p-tabPanel header="Manage Users">
            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                <sym-manage-users-tab [user]="user" *ngIf="user"></sym-manage-users-tab>
            </ng-template>
        </p-tabPanel>

</p-tabView>
</p-card>
```

Comment: Clicking on this error will showcase which html line causing this issue.

Comment: sounds like issue happends not because of the config, but because of something else

Comment: You mean this one https://angular.io/errors/NG0100, we have been through that and none the wiser.

Comment: I do not see any issue with this code. Ideally it should work.

Comment: Just today I faced an issue with the same error, in my case I was changing a component instance property in the ngAfterViewInit. I moved the code to ngOnInit instead and it worked.

Comment: @Andrew Can you create a stackblitz/codesandbox sample to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: As others mentioned, it’s unlikely that APP_INITIALIZER has anything to do with this. The more likely culprit is this.features, which is not initialized.

Comment: I think what @MikeOne says is true if you can see the response in network tab or console log. try to change this line : this.features = this.configurationService.configuration?.features || undefined;

Comment: @MikeOne yea it seems that way, Yes I see the response in the network tab, I also tried what MajiD said but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and assists. As I mentioned at the bottom of my question, using the ng-template seems to be used for lazy loading for the primeng p-tabView, in this situation the first tab that we are trying to display doesn't need lazy loading as it is the initial visible tab. Removing the ng-template to give this, then loads fine with no console error message.

```
    <p-tabView [(activeIndex)]="activeTab">
        
        <p-tabPanel header="General" *ngIf="features.userAdditionalDetails">
            <sym-general-tab [user]="user" *ngIf="user"></sym-general-tab>
        </p-tabPanel>
...
```